# Programmatically control check box behaviour in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view with check box in the each card in the view. I want to unchek all the other checkboxes when i clicks on a particular check box in the view(Condition can be like card contains an odd one etc). How can i do that? My adapter code is below.

```
public class PlatformAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlatformAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Batch> batches;
ArrayList<CourseSlug> courses;
boolean isInstituteStudent;

public void setBatches(ArrayList<Batch> batches) {
    this.batches = batches;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setCourses(ArrayList<CourseSlug> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public ArrayList<CourseSlug> getCourses() {
    return courses;
}

public ArrayList<Batch> getBatches() {
    return batches;
}

public void setInstituteStudent(boolean instituteStudent) {
    isInstituteStudent = instituteStudent;
}

public boolean isInstituteStudent() {
    return isInstituteStudent;
}

public PlatformAdapter() {
    courses = new ArrayList<>();
    batches = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_cell_platform_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (isInstituteStudent) {
        Batch batch = batches.get(position);
        holder.enrolment.setText(batch.getName());
        holder.selectEnrollment.setChecked(batch.isPreselect());
    } else {
        final CourseSlug course = courses.get(position);
        holder.enrolment.setText(course.getName());
        holder.selectEnrollment.setChecked(course.isPreselect());


    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return isInstituteStudent ? batches.size() : courses.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView enrolment;
    CheckBox selectEnrollment;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        enrolment = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_entrollment);
        selectEnrollment = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_select_entrollment);
        selectEnrollment.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                int index = getLayoutPosition();
                if(isInstituteStudent) {
                    Batch batch = batches.get(index);
                    batch.setPreselect(b);
                } else {
                    CourseSlug course = courses.get(index);
                    course.setPreselect(b);



                        }
                    }


        });

    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}
}
```

In my Courseslug class, there is a param called isTrue(); if ,courseSlug.isTrue()==true; then which card's check box is satisfying my condition, it gets checked and other unchecked/checked boxes gets unchecked. This is what i want done.

```
public class CourseSlug {
String name;
String slug;
boolean preselect;
boolean istrue;

public boolean isTrue() {
    return istrue;
}

public void setisTrue(boolean isTrue) {
    this.isTrue = istrue;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSlug() {
    return slug;
}

public void setSlug(String slug) {
    this.slug = slug;
}

public boolean isPreselect() {
    return preselect;
}

public void setPreselect(boolean preselect) {
    this.preselect = preselect;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the views are not necessarily visible, you need to keep a boolean state variable in your adapter. Toggle the variable when the user clicks the "master" checkbox. Then use this variable in `onBindViewHolder()` to set the checked state of the checkbox in each row.

Comment: Just edit your answer with the change in my code. so that i can reuse it directly

Comment: @Arjun this is not a code writing service. I have given you the information to help solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to android. That is why i may not able to do this. So thats why i am expecting from you.

Comment: @Arjun of course you can do it with a little effort. I have provided since hints to help you along the way.

Comment: Please do it. I got stuck with this. And in a fully exhausted state. That is why i am asking your help.

Comment: @Arjun my consulting fee is $200 per hour. I accept visa, master card, PayPal, and bitcoin.

Comment: Lol.this is not a work of one hour. Any ways thanks for your infor

Comment: @Arjun Which payment method do you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your `onBindViewHolder` method. Hope this is helpful :)

```
 private SparseArray<SparseBooleanArray> sparseArray = new SparseArray<>();

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

                final CourseSlug course = courses.get(position);
                holder.enrolment.setText(course.getName());
                holder.selectEnrollment.setChecked(course.isPreselect());
                holder.selectEnrollment.setId(position);
                holder.selectEnrollment.setChecked(false);

            if (sparseArray.get(holder.selectEnrollment.getId()) != null) {
                boolean isChecked = sparseArray.get(holder.selectEnrollment.getId()).get(holder.selectEnrollment.getId());
                holder.selectEnrollment.setChecked(isChecked);
            }

    holder.selectEnrollment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    sparseArray.clear();

            SparseBooleanArray checkedPosition = new SparseBooleanArray();
            checkedPosition.put(v.getId(), true);
            sparseArray.put(tagId, checkedPosition);
            notifySetDataChanged();
                }
            });


    }
```

Comment: What is  checkedGroupPositions. here ?

Comment: Please reply @Jeeva

Comment: @Arjun: sorry arjun corrected the code, here you go